# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row 01427. 00000 - "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is the query which is giving me error:

- If ed_temp and ed_indv_counters are joined using edg_trace_id.
- if Ed_eligiblity has current_elig_ind as 'P' then take that edg_trace_id else, take  edg_trace_id with current_elig_ind 'A'.

Query:

```
select distinct
       i.edg_trace_id,
       i.*
from   ed_indv_counters i,
       ed_temp e
where  e.case_num = '720335'   
and    e.payment_beg_dt<'30-JUL-2017' 
and    e.program_cd = 'TF' 
and    e.delete_sw='N' 
and    di_ind='Y'
and    counter_type_cd='TLP'
and    i.edg_trace_id in (
         CASE e.current_elig_ind
         WHEN 'P' then e.edg_trace_id
         ELSE (
           Select e1.edg_trace_id
           from   ed_temp e1
           where  e1.case_num='720335' 
           and    e1.program_cd = 'TF'
           and    e1.delete_sw='N'
           and    e1.current_elig_ind='A'
           and    e1.payment_beg_dt not in (
                    select payment_beg_dt
                    from   ed_temp e2
                    where  e2.current_elig_ind='P'
                    and    e2.case_num='720335'  
                    and    e2.delete_sw='N'
                    and    e2.program_cd = 'TF'
                  )
         )
         END
       )
order by i.counter_begin_dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `UNION ALL` and mutually exclusive filters rather than a `CASE` statement:

```
select distinct
       i.edg_trace_id,
       i.*
from   ed_indv_counters i,
       ed_temp e
where  e.case_num = '720335'   
and    e.payment_beg_dt < DATE '2017-07-30' -- Use a date literal rather than string 
and    e.program_cd = 'TF' 
and    e.delete_sw='N' 
and    di_ind='Y'
and    counter_type_cd='TLP'
and    i.edg_trace_id in (
         SELECT e.edg_trace_id
         FROM   DUAL
         WHEN   e.current_elig_ind = 'P'
       UNION ALL
         Select e1.edg_trace_id
         from   ed_temp e1
         where  ( e.current_elig_ind <> 'P' OR e.current_elig_ind IS NULL )
         and    e1.case_num='720335'
         and    e1.program_cd = 'TF'
         and    e1.delete_sw='N'
         and    e1.current_elig_ind='A'
         and    e1.payment_beg_dt not in (
                  select payment_beg_dt
                  from   ed_temp e2
                  where  e2.current_elig_ind='P'
                  and    e2.case_num='720335'  
                  and    e2.delete_sw='N'
                  and    e2.program_cd = 'TF'
                )
     )
order by i.counter_begin_dt;
```

Comment: This query works perfectly, but is there any way of tuning it. ed_temp table has got 100 columns and joining that is giving me performance issue